# Entity Data Model Wizard can't find my Connection

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework

In VS 2019, I created a connection in Server Explorer. The connection is for Oracle and it passed the Test and was created successfully. However, when I go to create an ADO.NET Entity Data Model, on the screen which asks "Which data connection should your application use to connect to the database?" and has a combo box immediately below that question, there are no connections from which to choose. Why doesn't my connection show up there? I even restarted Visual Studio with no difference.

Comment: Does the connect string exist in your app.config/web.config?

Comment: I did a search for the username I entered when creating the Data Connection and it is not in the App.config.